# Close/Open MatAccordion from Side Menu/Nav in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, accordion, angular-material2

I have application and have accordion on a page. I have option/menu in side nav in `app.components.ts` and want to open/close accordion items from side menus.
I tried to access Expan

```
@ContentChildren('matExpansionPanel') matExpansionPanelElements:QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

On I get 0 values in this.
my side menu are in `app.component.html` and my accordion list is in other `component/page`.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot jump from one component to another if you don't follow the chain

Component1 -> Component2 -> Component3.

Create the reference of a parent component to a child with @ViewChild and from component 1 call a method of component 2 that invokes a method of component 3, so you can close the panels from app.component

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(MediumComponent) medium: MediumComponent;
[...]
collapsePanel(): void {
    medium.collapsePanel();
}
```

medium.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion;
[...]
collapsePanel(): void {
    accordion.closeAll()
}
```